# reading a text file from multiple folders with loop

Tags: php

I am creating a php page that will read a certain .txt file from every folder in the directory using loop. My directory structure looks like this:

root/

- Folder1 --> data.txt (with value "1")
- Folder2 --> data.txt (with value "2")
- foldernames.txt (with values "Folder1" and "Folder2" in every line.)
- readfolderdata.php

readfolderdata.php

```
<?php
$file = "foldernames.txt";
if ( file_exists( $file )) {
$page = join("",file("$file"));
$folder = explode("\n", $page);
for($x=0;$x<count($folder);$x++){

    if($folder[$x]!=''){
        $txtfile = $folder[$x].'/data.txt';
        $handle = fopen($txtfile, 'r');
        $data = fread($handle,filesize($txtfile));
        fclose($handle);
        echo $folder[$x]."<br>".$data; 
        }
}
?>
```

Now the codes above only reads the data.txt from the second folder which is Folder2. And an error "**failed to open stream**" in reading the data.txt from the first folder Folder1, though the data.txt in Folder1 exists. If I remove the "**Folder2**" from foldernames.txt it works perfectly, the error occurs when there are 2 or more folders.

Comment: a print_r of $folder can help

Comment: print_r displays an array "**Array ( [0] => Folder1 [1] => Folder2 )**", that means reading the foldernames.txt has no problems, but with accessing the data.txt file from the first folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$file = "foldernames.txt";
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line) // Look through lines, $line is now folder name
{
    $value = file_get_contents($line."/data.txt");
    // Do whatever you want with your value, example echo:
    echo $value;
}
```

This code echos all data.txt values.